# Logstash does not close file descriptors

Tags: linux, logstash, file-descriptor

I am using Logstash 2.2.4. 
My current configuration

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/data/events/*/*.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => "json"
    ignore_older => 0
    max_open_files => 46000
  }
}
filter {
  if [type] not in ["A", "B", "C"] {
  drop {}
}
}
output {
  HTTP {
    http_method => "post"
    workers => 3
    url => "http://xxx.amazonaws.com/event"
  }
}
```

In an input folder, I have about 25000 static (never updatable) txt files.

I configured --pipeline-workers to 16. In described configuration LS process running 1255 threads and opens about 2,560,685 file descriptors.

After some investigation, I found that LS keeping open files descriptor for all the files in the input folder and HTTP output traffic became very slow.

My question is why LS does not close file descriptor of already processed  (transferred) files or implementing kind of input files pagination?

Maybe someone meets the same problem? If yes, please share your solution.
Thanks.

Comment: The Logstash file input [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) states that "Stream events from files, normally by tailing them in a manner similar to tail -0F but optionally reading them from the beginning.". So it's normal that the file descriptors are not closed.

Comment: thank you for the answer, then what are the alternatives? or maybe workarounds?

Comment: If I understand you problem right, you just want to transfer the content of the files to ES. In that case, you could do it in multiple times (once per folder perhaps), so that you don't have the file descriptor problem. Or, modify the file input plugin to just read the content of the file and then stop (in ruby). Or ditch Logstash and just write in your favorite language an app reading the files, parsing the json and sending everything to ES.

Comment: thank you for your help. Implementing your own application this is something that I try to avoid do not implement and test many edge cases like partial file transfer, retries in case of network interruptions, etc. According to his [link](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/48), required by me and other developers behaviour of LS is under development right now.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank for the info